# How can a Perl regex re-use part of the previous match for the next match?

Tags: regex, perl

I need some Perl regular expression help.  The following snippet of code:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
my $str = "In this example, A plus B equals C, D plus E plus F equals G and H plus I plus J plus K equals L"; 
my $word = "plus"; 
my @results = ();
1 while $str =~ s/(.{2}\b$word\b.{2})/push(@results,"$1\n")/e;
print @results;
```

Produces the following output:

```
A plus B
D plus E
2 plus F
H plus I
4 plus J
5 plus K
```

What I want to see is this, where a character already matched can appear in a new match in a different context:

```
A plus B
D plus E
E plus F
H plus I
I plus J
J plus K
```

How do I change the regular expression to get this result?  Thanks --- Dan

Comment: Thanks Greg, Sinan and Michael for the quick response.  Full Disclosure: the example cited is a simplification, $str is actually 500k chars of text from a product user manual, $word is one element in a long list of possible word hits, {2} is actually {35} and can capture any characters found around "plus" in the text in order to build a complete concordance of how "plus" is used in the doc, so points awarded for fastest performance --- Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General advice: Don't use `s///` when you want `m//`. Be specific in what you match.

The answer is [`pos`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'In this example, ' . 'A plus B equals C, ' .
          'D plus E plus F equals G ' .
          'and H plus I plus J plus K equals L';

my $word = "plus";

my @results;

while ( $str =~ /([A-Z] $word [A-Z])/g ) {
    push @results, $1;
    pos($str) -= 1;
}

print "'$_'" for @results;
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> b
'A plus B'
'D plus E'
'E plus F'
'H plus I'
'I plus J'
'J plus K'
```

Comment: Ah, essentially the same answer but you cleaned up the regex too.

Comment: `pos` just feels cleaner than `substr`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `m//g` instead of `s///` and assign to the `pos` function to rewind the match location before the second term:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str  = 'In this example, A plus B equals C, D plus E plus F equals G and H plus I plus J plus K equals L';
my $word = 'plus';
my @results;

while ($str =~ /(.{2}\b$word\b(.{2}))/g) {
    push @results, "$1\n";
    pos $str -= length $2;
}
print @results;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a lookahead:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
my $str = "In this example, A plus B equals C, D plus E "
        . "plus F equals G and H plus I plus J plus K equals L"; 
my $word = "plus"; 
my $chars = 2;
my @results = ();

push @results, $1 
  while $str =~ /(?=((.{0,$chars}?\b$word\b).{0,$chars}))\2/g;

print "'$_'\n" for @results;
```

Within the lookahead, capturing group 1 matches the word along with a variable number of leading and trailing context characters, up to whatever maximum you've set.  When the lookahead finishes, the backreference `\2` matches "for real" whatever was captured by group 2, which is the same as group 1 except that it stops at the end of the word.  That sets `pos` where you want it, without requiring you to calculate how many characters you actually matched after the word.

Comment: Thanks for posting, I learned more about regex looking at this.  I wonder, which is faster, this solution or Sinan's which uses pos()?

Comment: They're not really equivalent. Sinan's code, which is based on your original question, matches exactly 2 extra characters at either end, and bumps `pos` back exactly one position. Mine allows for a variable number of context characters (with 2 being the max in this case), which seems more realistic after reading your "Full Disclosure" comment.  My solution can more usefully be compared to ysth's, and I would expect his to be faster because it lets the regex engine find the match for `\b$word\b` without putting a reluctant quantifier in its way.

Answer (score 1):

Given the "Full Disclosure" comment (but assuming `.{0,35}`, not `.{35}`), I'd do

```
use List::Util qw/max min/;
my $context = 35;
while ( $str =~ /\b$word\b/g ) {
    my $pre = substr( $str, max(0, $-[0] - $context), min( $-[0], $context ) );
    my $post = substr( $str, $+[0], $context );
    my $match = substr( $str, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0] );
    $pre =~ s/.*\n//s;
    $post =~ s/\n.*//s;
    push @results, "$pre$match$post";
}
print for @results;
```

You'd skip the substitutions if you really meant `(?s:.{0,35})`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
my $str = "In this example, A plus B equals C, D plus E plus F equals G and H plus I plus J plus K equals L"; 
my $word = "plus"; 
my @results = ();
my $i = 0;
while (substr($str, $i) =~ /(.{2}\b$word\b.{2})/) {
    push @results, "$1\n";
    $i += $-[0] + 1;
}
print @results;
```

It's not terribly Perl-ish, but it works and it doesn't use too many obscure regular expression tricks. However, you might have to look up the function of the special variable `@-` in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Answer (score 0):

don't have to use regex. basically, just split up the string, use a loop to go over each items, check for "plus" , then get the word from before and after.

```
my $str = "In this example, A plus B equals C, D plus E plus F equals G and H plus I plus J plus K equals L"; 
@s = split /\s+/,$str;
for($i=0;$i<=scalar @s;$i++){
    if ( "$s[$i]"  eq "plus" ){
        print "$s[$i-1] plus $s[$i+1]\n";
    }
}
```